# Grouping same nodes into single parent

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML content like below:

```
<details>
      <name>Name 1</name>
      <name>Name 2</name>
      <name>Name 3</name>
      <address>Address 1</address>
      <address>Address 2</address>
      <address>Address 3</address>
      <address>Address 4</address>
  ....
</details>
```

I would like to get an output as like below:

```
<details>
 <names>      
      <name>Name 1</name>
      <name>Name 2</name>
      <name>Name 3</name>
 </names>
 <addresses>
     <address>Address 1</address>
     <address>Address 2</address>
     <address>Address 3</address>
     <address>Address 4</address>
 </addresses>
```

...

I tried with the following XSL but I am not getting the desired output:

```
 <xsl:template match="address">
    <addresses>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </addresses>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the names and number of child elements of the `details` element? In that case it suffices to use

```
<xsl:template match="details">
  <xsl:copy>
   <names>
     <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
   </names>
   <addresses>
     <xsl:copy-of select="address"/>
   </addresses>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

If you don't know the names and number of child elements you can group by the name although then generating the plural for the wrapper element name might be difficult (i.e. name -> names but address -> addresses):

```
<xsl:template match="details">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="local-name(.)">
     <xsl:element name="{if (ends-with(current-grouping-key(), 's') then concat(current-grouping-key(), 'es') else concat(current-grouping-key(), 's')}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

That should give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Yes, I know the name of the child elements, so the first answer is suits for me. Thank you very much again.